# MongoDb aggregate I can't format date directly in the aggregate query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this model:

```
const HistorySchema = new Schema({
  // Other fields
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

I am using an aggregate query to get some data and trying to format the date in the same time:

```
const final_project_option = {
  $project: {
    // Other projections
    date: {
      $dateFromString: {
        date: "$date",
      },
    },
  },
};

const pipeline = [
  // Other options
  final_project_option,
];
const history_events_with_aggregate = await History.aggregate(pipeline);
```

But, I am receiving this error:

> error MongoError: $dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a
> string, found: date with value 2021-07-06T12:24:45.707Z

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: `$dateFromString` the name of the operator describes that convert date from string, and your schema field is date type so this operator can't work, you can use `$toDate` operator.

Comment: That makes no difference. This is what I wrote: ` date: { $toDate: "$date" }` but the result is the same

Comment: ok, *format the date in the same time* => can you explain in what time?

Comment: Just format it like this: "Year-month-day hour-minute-second"

Comment: there is a operator to format date from date type [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

Comment: I used it in the beginning but the app throws an error, the one I mentioned in my question.

Comment: actually, it is different what you have used `$dateFromString` and i have suggested `$dateToString`.

Comment: Aw I'm sorry. Yeah. That should work. Thank you.